# WMPLib Music plays but when I switch tabs it stops

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I have C# application for a Food Truck. I have some music playing when customers view the menu. On the menu form I have four tabs. I have the WMPLib code in form load. When the form loads the music begins playing however when I switch to a different tab the music stops. I have debugged but there is nothing there to really see since it runs the lines but just stops when you switch tabs. Any ideas on how to keep the music playing when switching tabs on the main form. I would like it to play continuous not just start again on each tab. Thanks. Here is an image of the form with the tabs.

[image]

Here is the form load code:

```
try
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

    wplayer.URL = "runningdownadream.mp3";
    wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);
    wplayer.controls.play();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No music. Windows Media Player not installed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: An image of what you are talking about (your form) would be helpful.  You may want to try using `BackgroundWorker`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried adding a background worker...it played the music but it still stopped when i switched tabs...didnt keep running in the background.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? What controls do are you using? Do you have a single form with a `TabControl` on it?

Comment: Winforms...Multitab control when I switch tabs the music stops...trying to figure out how to have it running in the background for all tabs

Comment: Winforms and TabControl yes...i added image so you can see the tabs

Comment: You should not be using WinForms for applications like this - this is one of those many reasons. I strongly recommend you start-over in WPF or WinUI3.0, if possible.

Comment: Oh sorry I have to do this in Winforms....its a requirement

Comment: @tech127956 This wont end well...

Comment: well i figured out a way to do it...i can run it on mouse move with some if statements...i just dont like it because there is about a 30 second delay before it starts the music

Comment: trying to find a better way where the music starts at the beginning and keeps playing continously

Comment: @tech127956 You need to store the `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer` instance in a field - otherwise it will be GCd by the runtime because it has no forward references. Also, there are other reasons for exceptions to be thrown besides a broken `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer` COM registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to play an MP3 in the background using `WMPLib`, try the following:

Create a class (name: HelperMp3.cs)

**HelperMp3.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AxWMPLib;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WmpLibTest
{
    public class HelperMp3 : IDisposable
    {
        public delegate void EventHandlerMediaError(object sender, object pMediaObject);
        public delegate void EventHandlerPlayStateChanged(object sender, int newValue);

        //events
        public event EventHandlerMediaError Mp3MediaError;
        public event EventHandlerPlayStateChanged Mp3PlayStateChanged;

        public string MP3Filename { get; set; } //fully-qualified MP3 filename

        private WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer _wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

        public HelperMp3()
        {
            //subscribe to events (add event handlers)
            _wplayer.PlayStateChange += _wplayer_PlayStateChange;
            _wplayer.MediaError += _wplayer_MediaError;
        }

        private void _wplayer_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error (MediaError): " + pMediaObject.ToString());

            //if subscribed to event, raise event, otherwise throw exception
            if (Mp3MediaError != null)
            {
                //raise event
                Mp3MediaError(this, pMediaObject);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Error (MediaError): " + pMediaObject.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void _wplayer_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
        {
            //Undefined = 0,
            //Stopped = 1,
            //Paused = 2,
            //Playing = 3,
            //ScanForward = 4,
            //ScanReverse = 5,
            //Buffering = 6,
            //Waiting = 7,
            //MediaEnded = 8,
            //Transitioning = 9,
            //Ready = 10,
            //Reconnecting = 11,
            //Last = 12

            if (Mp3PlayStateChanged != null)
            {
                //raise event
                Mp3PlayStateChanged(this, NewState);
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("_wplayer_PlayStateChange: " + NewState.ToString());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_wplayer != null)
            {
                _wplayer.controls.stop();

                //unsubscribe from events (add event handlers)
                _wplayer.PlayStateChange -= _wplayer_PlayStateChange;
                _wplayer.MediaError -= _wplayer_MediaError;

                //release all resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_wplayer);

                _wplayer = null;
            }
        }


        public void Start()
        {
            if (_wplayer != null)
            {
                _wplayer.controls.play();
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_wplayer != null)
            {
                _wplayer.controls.stop();
            }
        }

        public void PlayMp3()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MP3Filename: " + MP3Filename);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MP3Filename) || !System.IO.File.Exists(MP3Filename))
            {
                throw new Exception("MP3Filename not specified.");
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Playing mp3...");

            //set value
            _wplayer.URL = MP3Filename;
            _wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);

            _wplayer.controls.play();

        }
    }
}
```

In the form (ex: Form1) code, create an instance of the class above:

```
 private HelperMp3 _helperMp3 = new HelperMp3();
```

Then create a method that starts the music:

```
private void StartMusic(string mp3Filename)
{    
    //set property
    helperMp3.MP3Filename = mp3Filename;

    Task t1 = Task.Run(_helperMp3.PlayMp3);
}
```

Subscribe to the `Load` event for the form (ex: Form1_Load) and add the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ToDo: replace with your MP3 filename
    StartMusic(@"C:\Temp\Test.mp3");
}
```

Subscribe to the `FormClosed` event for the form (ex: Form1_FormClosed) and add the following code:

**Form1_FormClosed**

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_helperMp3 != null)
    {
        _helperMp3.Dispose();
        _helperMp3 = null;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, one can use `BackgroundWorker`. If using `BackgroundWorker`, in `HelperMp3.cs` change method `PlayMp3` to the following:

```
public void PlayMp3(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("MP3Filename: " + MP3Filename);

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MP3Filename) || !System.IO.File.Exists(MP3Filename))
    {
        throw new Exception("MP3Filename not specified.");
    }

    if (worker.CancellationPending || e.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Playing mp3...");

    //set value
    _wplayer.URL = MP3Filename;
    _wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);

    _wplayer.controls.play();

}
```

**Note**: If using `BackgroundWorker`, the `BackgroundWorker` will complete, but the `WMPLib` control will still be running.

Comment: Thanks...I appreciate it